# Javascript Clear fields Function Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html

This is function that i created for clear text fields but when enter any custom values it doesn't clear

```
function clear(){

    document.getElementById('bmw1').value="";
    document.getElementById('bmw2').value="";
    document.getElementById('ans').value="";


}
```

The fields which created in html

```
<input type="text" id="bmw1" placeholder="Enter 1st Number"/>
<input type="text" id="bmw2" placeholder="Enter 2nd Number"/>
<input type="text" id="ans" placeholder="Answer"/>
<button type="button" onClick="clear()">Clear Values</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the js function name from clear() to something else. Because clear() is a java script built in function/method.

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel?  You can do that with basic HTML:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Just make sure that is inside your `form` and it will clear all the values.

Comment: I already Know this reset button but is there a way that we clear fields with function

Answer (score 0):

I believe JavaScript already has a clear() function, try renaming your method.  The following works for me :

```
function erase(){
        document.getElementById('bmw1').value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with name of function which is already reserved for Document.

Please change your function name to other and it will work well.